# Is it possible to connect to multiple remote nodes?

Tags: full-node, nodes, remote-node

A big drawback with connecting to a remote node is adding a central point of failure by trusting that node. Being able to connect to multiple remote nodes would reduce this significantly - is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

No, connecting to multiple remote nodes would *increase* your risk as you are then having to trust more remote nodes.

Remote nodes are not a centralization risk in any case (you can use *any* remote node that is open and you can always use your own node). Using a remote node, your risk is hoping they are not a bad actor (e.g. they could be logging your usage/IP, not on the correct chain, not broadcasting your transactions). If these risks are unacceptable for you, run your *own* node, local or remote.

Comment: If you are checking the most recent blocks from multiple nodes instead of just one wouldn’t that be less trust? Just connecting and trusting one seems riskier

Comment: No, because you are only seemingly solving one issue whilst at the same time increasing risk with other issues. If you want to reduce risk, use your own node (local or remote). Bottom line, *public* remote nodes are just a convenience, they are not risk free.

Comment: Yeh I get the trade offs of using a remote node. But why would checking say 10 nodes on the block state before broadcasting my tx over 1 be less risky?

Comment: You want to divulge your IP address to 1 public node or 10??

Comment: IP is less of a concern than getting fed incorrect blocks, could connect to 10 Tor nodes to get around that also.

Comment: There is nothing stopping you specify any remote node you like. You are not forced into using any specific node. And if IP tracking is not a concern to you (amongst other privacy you lose using public remote nodes), then sure, use any you like.